# Can I make this numerical integration continuously differentiable?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, spline

Suppose I have the discrete values $f(x_i)$ for every $x_i$ greater than some $\varepsilon$, and I want to numerically calculate the following integral:
\begin{equation}
 n = \int_\varepsilon^\infty f(x)Z(x)dx
\end{equation}
with the known function $Z(x)$.

We can approximate $f(x)=f(x_i)$ for $x\in[x_{i-},x_{i+}]$ with $x_{i-}=x_i-\dfrac{\Delta x}{2}$ and $x_{i+}=x_i+\dfrac{\Delta x}{2}$,
and calculate the above integral like:
\begin{equation}
 n \approx f(x_k)\int_{\varepsilon}^{x_{k+}} Z(x)dx + \sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty} f(x_j)\int_{x_{j-}}^{x_{j+}} Z(x)dx
\end{equation}
with $\varepsilon\in[x_{k-},x_{k+}]$. First consider the case of $Z(x)=\sqrt{x-\varepsilon}$, for which the above expression gives a continuously differentiable
approximation with respect to $\varepsilon$.

Next, consider another function $Z(x)=c$. We can check and see that the above approximation is no longer differentiable when $\varepsilon$ moves continuously from one 
$[x_{i-},x_{i+}]$ to the next $[x_{(i+1)-},x_{(i+1)+}]$. In order to have a continously differentiable approximation to $n$, we can use a piecewise linear interpolation for
$f(x)$. That is, 
\begin{align}
 & f(x) \approx \dfrac{f(x_{j+1})-f(x_j)}{\Delta x}(x-x_j) + f(x_j)  \qquad\quad   x\in [x_{j-},x_{j+}]~,   \\
 & n \approx \int_{\varepsilon}^{x_{k+}} f(x)Z(x)dx + \sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty} \int_{x_{j-}}^{x_{j+}} f(x)Z(x)dx
\end{align}
results in a continuous derivative $\dfrac{dn}{d\varepsilon}$.

Is there some piecewise interpolation for $f(x)$ in order to make the above mentioned numerical approximation continuously differentiable 
for the function $Z(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-\varepsilon}}$?

Comment: You can use Lagrange polynomials to create a continuously differentiable $f(x)$ that passes through all your $\left(x_i,f(x_i)\right)$.

Comment: I have more than one thousand points, and having a Lagrange polynomial passing through all of them causes sharp oscillations.
I intentionally talked about a linear piecewise interpolation in the case $Z(x)=c$ to show that I am looking for a simple function to do the job.
@tomi